# Event Kit - edit repeating event

Tags: swift, eventkit, ekevent

```
 func editFutureEventToCalendar(id:String,title: String, description: String?,alarams :[EKAlarm],location:String,contacts:[GenParticipants],repeatString :String,timeZone:NSTimeZone, startDate: NSDate, endDate: NSDate , isAllDay :Bool,calendar:EKCalendar,StruLocation:EKStructuredLocation?)->Bool {
    let eventStore = EventsManager.getEventStore()



    let event = EventsManager.geteventID(id: id)

    let ocdate = event.occurrenceDate

    event.title = title
    event.startDate = startDate as Date
    event.endDate = endDate as Date
    event.notes = description
    event.calendar = calendar
   // event.occurrenceDate = ocdate


    event.timeZone = timeZone as TimeZone //timezoneNSTimeZone() as TimeZone //timeZone as TimeZone


    event.isAllDay = isAllDay

    if StruLocation != nil {
        event.structuredLocation = StruLocation
    }else {

        event.structuredLocation = StruLocation
    }


    if repeatString != "None" {

        if event.hasRecurrenceRules {


            let rrrl = event.recurrenceRules

            for i in rrrl! {


                event.removeRecurrenceRule(i)

            }

        }


        let rule = EventsManager.getRepeatValue(repeatString)//self.getRepeatValue(option: repeat)
        event.addRecurrenceRule(rule!)
    }else if repeatString == "None"{


        if event.hasRecurrenceRules {


            let rrrl = event.recurrenceRules

            for i in rrrl! {


                event.removeRecurrenceRule(i)

            }

        }


    }






    for item in alarams {

        event.addAlarm(item)
    }
   // event.location = location
    //        let formatter = CNContactFormatter()
    //        formatter.style  =
    var attendees = [EKParticipant]()
    //        for item in contacts {
    //
    //            let con = event.(contact: item)
    //            attendees.append(con!)
    //
    //        }



    do {

        try eventStore.save(event, span: .futureEvents, commit: true)

        //try eventStore.save(event, span: .thisEvent)

        return true

    } catch let e as NSError {


        EZAlertController.alert(e.debugDescription)
    }



    return false 
}
```

I have this function for editing all the future events in repeat series - if i edit the event in between the series of events its deleting all the previous events and editing future events .
i want it to edit all the events in series . 
I am using eventKit not eventKitUI . i dont want eventkitUI.
How to edit this function to do the same or do i have to fetch the event differently as the identifier are same for all the events in repeating series?